# Sharepoint date function in conditional formula

Tags: sharepoint, date, conditional-statements, addition, formula

I want to add some days when the (type calculated)[No. vacante] column  has "vacante 1" or "vacante 2" my code is below. The error I am getting is a syntax error or that the formula is not supported, but i can not figure out where the error is.

```
=IF([No. vacante]="vacante 1",(DATE(YEAR([fecha ingreso]),MONTH([fecha ingreso]),DAY([fecha ingreso])+1)),
IF([No. vacante]="vacante 2",(DATE(YEAR([fecha ingreso]),MONTH([fecha ingreso]),DAY([fecha ingreso])+2) )),
IF([No. vacante]="vacante 3",(DATE(YEAR([fecha ingreso]),MONTH([fecha ingreso]),DAY([fecha ingreso])+3))))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with the provided formula:

- The third IF statement is nested at the wrong level (inside of IF #1 instead of IF #2).
- The third IF statement also needs a default value as its third parameter, so that the formula always returns some value.

Every IF statement in Sharepoint needs three values: the expression to be evaluated, the value if true, and the value if false. Microsoft provides [a more detailed explanation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/if-function-HA001161010.aspx).

I believe the below formula should do the job. Make sure to replace `default_value_goes_here` with an appropriate default to be used if `[No. vacante]` does not equal any of `vacante 1`, `vacante 2`, or `vacante 3`.

```
=
    IF(
        [No. vacante]="vacante 1", 
        (DATE
            (YEAR([fecha ingreso]),
            MONTH([fecha ingreso]),
            DAY([fecha ingreso])+1)
        ),
        IF(
            [No. vacante]="vacante 2",
            (DATE
                (YEAR([fecha ingreso]),
                MONTH([fecha ingreso]),
                DAY([fecha ingreso])+2)
            ),
            IF(
                [No. vacante]="vacante 3",
                (DATE
                    (YEAR([fecha ingreso]),
                    MONTH([fecha ingreso]),
                    DAY([fecha ingreso])+3)
                ),
                default_value_goes_here
            )
        )
    )
```